# Showing that $U$ is a normal subgroup of $N_G(U)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am given a group $G$, a subgroup $H \le G$ and the normalizer of $U$ in $G$, $N_g(U) = \{ g \in G: U^g = g^{-1}Ug = U\}$. I am asked to prove that $U$ is a normal subgroup of $N_G(U)$.

Isn't this obvious? Since both $U$ and $N_G(U)$ are subgroups of $G$, the only things to prove are that
(i) $U \subset N_G(U)$ and
(ii) U is normal in $N_G(U)$.

But both things seem trivial to me because (i) of course $U^u=U$ for $u \in U$ and (ii) the normality condition $gU = Ug \forall g \in N_G(U)$ is simply equivalent to $U^g = g^{-1}Ug$ from the definition of the normalizer.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Nope - that's the answer.

Comment: As simple as that, @Marc...and you deserve an upvote for showing your work. +1

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, curious and Timbuc!

Comment: Maybe you're supposed to show that $N_G(U)$ is a subgroup of $G$, too.  That would warrant a calculation at least.

Comment: Yes, I had to show this also and I didn't have a problem with it. I only got suspicious about what I asked here because it required almost no work.